# Array contains more than it should

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino

I have:

```
int arraySize(int arr[]) {
  int size = 0;
  for(int i=0;i>-1;) {
    Serial.println(arr[i]);
    if(arr[i] != NULL) {
      size++;
      i++;
    }
    else {
      break;
    }
  }
  return size;
}

void loop() {
  int stuff[2] = {5, 6};

  arraySize(stuff);
  delay(2000);
}
```

There should only be 2 items printing out (5 and 6), but I'm getting 5, 6, 13312, 23296.

What is going wrong?

Comment: `for(int i=0;i>-1;)` are you sure about this line? Also `if(arr[i] != NULL)` will not check whether you have reached the end of the array

Comment: Your `arraySize` is a weird way of getting the length of an array of pointers that ends with `NULL`… but you have an array of `int`, and it does not end with `NULL`.

Comment: If your array isn't NULL terminated you're going to run off the rails in a big way. This line combined with `i++` makes no sense.  `for(int i=0;i>-1;)`.

Comment: Arrays are fixed size.  If you have an array you need to know the size. The function passing the array has to already know it's size.

Answer (score 4):

Neglecting the potential for undefined behaviour encountered on integer overflow and assuming there is not a `0` in the array which would break the loop, `for (int i = 0; i >-1;)` is going to loop infinitely as you only ever increment `i`.

Alas you cannot resort to clever tricks to get the length of an array that's been passed to a function. The behaviour on reading an out-of-bounds index of an array is *undefined*.

The normal way of dealing with this is to keep track of the size of the array (as a `size_t` type) and pass that into functions that require the array. Another alternative is to use a magic number to signal the end of the array, rather like the `NUL` terminator of a C-style string.

Comment: The loop isn't infinite if there is a `NULL` present in the array - there is a `break`.   I agree it's clumsy, and with your comments concerning undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Peter: Thanks for the spot, I've fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is by the part `for(int i=0;i>-1;)` and `i++;` it means the condition is always true.

Comment: @ArnavBorborah the problem is that the loop regardless of the `break` overflows the buffer, because it will accessing elements past beyond the array limits until it finds a 0.

Answer (score 1):

Your code expects a NULL terminated array, but your array is not. I would try

```
$ cat dummy.c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

size_t arraySize(const int *arr) {
  const int *p = arr;
  while (1) {
    if (*p == 0)
      break;
    // commented out for testing the code..
    //Serial.println(*p);
    printf("%d\n", *p);
    p++;
  }
  return p - arr;
}

int main(__attribute__((unused)) int argc, __attribute__((unused)) char **argv)
{
  int stuff[3] = {5, 6, 0};
  printf("size: %ld\n", arraySize(stuff));

  return(0);
}
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -o dummy dummy.c
$ ./dummy 
5
6
size: 2
```

I've commented out the `Serial.println()` part, because I guess that is some API on your system (Arduino?).

Comment: why do you cast `argc` and `argv` and do nothing with them?

Comment: ...if you can remove them completely.

Comment: I always compile my code with -Wall -Wextra -Werror to catch stupid mistakes. Updated my answer to use the IMHO less readable GCC type attributes instead.

Comment: Of course in the case of `stuff` you can get rid of `arraySize()` completely and simply use`size_t size = sizeof(stuff)/sizeof(int);` Unless of course the `Serial` part has some relevance...

Answer (score 0):

In the loop, you are printing array[i] before checking if it's null. 
That would only explain the first strange number. Not sure about the second number.